# Remove link CSS styles from only one link

Tags: css

I purchased a template for a client of mine. this template has a parent CSS style apparently for ALL LINKS on the page. (this is what the comments say on the .css above this specific style)

Now, I've created a section at the bottom, near the footer that is a different background color from the rest of the site, so i want to somehow override the CSS and give it my own parameters without tinkering to much with the rest of the site because the grey color and white mouseover doesn't look good, is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Give that section an ID attribute and use that when defining your styles. So something like...

HTML

```
<div id="my-section">
  your section is here
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* your section's styling is here */
#my-section {
  ...
}

#my-section .sub-parts {
  ...
}

#my-section a {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just create a new class and give an !important to the property you want to override like this:

```
body a {font-size:10px;}/* template general style */

a.mydiv{font-size: 16px !important;}/* your style  */
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
/* Provided in your template */
a {
  color: gray;
}

/* Added for footer */
#footer a {
  color: blue; /* Or what color you want. */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Some HTML provided in your template -->
<div id="footer">
   <!-- Your footer content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a more specific style to override the more general style. You can learn more about **CSS Specificity** here: [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 0):

You do this by:

1. Assigning IDs to each anchor
2. Creating a class to be used on each anchor
3. Changing the default color by searching for where the color is assigned in the template
4. Colorize by parent elements and using specifiers.

Option 3 is the most straightforward, but puts you in the position where the colors are no longer the same. And, as is most often the case, you'd prefer to not interfere with the template. If you choose the non-intrusive route, then options 1, 2 and 4 are the best.

But, option 1 *can become quite tedious for large documents and by extension, so is option 2* - since they have to be entered on a case by case basis. Most often this technique is used if you need to override the color for usually a few elements.

However, if you work with a lot of anchors and you need to apply this color to them, then **option 4 is your best bet as the color assignment and can be done via by class specification or by id of a parent element** - which *greatly* simplifies your life.

Example:

If this is what your HTML looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
<a class="mylink" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>
<a id="link1" href="http://www.wikipedia.org/">Wikipedia</a>

<div id="colorize_by_id">
    <a href="http://www.reddit.com/">Reddit</a>
</div>

<div class="colorize">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS is defined in this kind of manner:

```
/*This is an example of what the template does to each anchor tag*/
a {
    color: green;
}

/*However, by adding a class to the anchor, you can override the "default" color.*/
a.mylink {
    color: blue;
}

/*And, if you wished to use on a case by case basis, you can do it by applying it per id*/
a#link1 {
    color: red;
}

/*Change the color of the anchors on an id by id basis*/
div#colorize_by_id a {
    color: magenta;
}

/*Change the color of the anchors on a class basis*/
div.colorize a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

As you can see, 
See it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/4TMpy/